# MFMailComposeViewController check if pressed send

Tags: objective-c, email, uiviewcontroller, sendmail

Is there any way of checking if the user actually presses the send button when using the MFMailComposeViewController class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
-(void)sendMail
{
  MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  [mailer setMailComposeDelegate:self];
  //do the rest of the mail composing
  ...
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
  //don't forget to dismiss the controller
  [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  if(result == MFMailComposeResultSent)
  {
    //the user sent the mail
  }
}
```